# IndexError: index 13 is out of bounds for dimension 1 with size 13- YOLOv8 Object detection

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, object-detection, yolov8

I am training a model of YOLOv8 on a custom dataset which is DeepFashion2 dataset. The dataset has 13 classes. and I gave the nc=13 in the yaml file, but when I start the training I found the error of **IndexError: index 13 is out of bounds for dimension 1 with size 13**

I tried to solve the problem by minimizing the nc to be 12, but that does not work and displays another error that the nc should match the classes number

**Here is the yaml file:**

```
train: E:/DeepFashion2Dataset/training/train/images
val: E:/DeepFashion2Dataset/val/images
test: E:/DeepFashion2Dataset/test/images

nc: 13
names: ['short sleeve top', 'long sleeve top', 'short sleeve outwear', 'long sleeve outwear', 'vest', 'sling', 'shorts', 'trousers', 'skirt', 'short sleeve dress', 'long sleeve dress', 'vest dress', 'sling dress']
```

**Here is the training code:**

```
pip install ultralytics
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Load a model
#model = YOLO("yolov8n.yaml")  # build a new model from scratch
model=YOLO()
#model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")  # load a pretrained model (recommended for training)
model.train(data="E:/DeepFashion2Dataset/training/data.yaml", epochs=30, task="detect")


Print("Done Successfully...")
```

**the ourput:**

```
Ultralytics YOLOv8.0.85  Python-3.11.1 torch-2.0.0+cpu CPU
yolo\engine\trainer: task=detect, mode=train, model=yolov8n.pt, data=E:/DeepFashion2Dataset/training/data.yaml, epochs=30, patience=50, batch=16, imgsz=640, save=True, save_period=-1, cache=False, device=None, workers=8, project=None, name=None, exist_ok=False, pretrained=False, optimizer=SGD, verbose=True, seed=0, deterministic=True, single_cls=False, image_weights=False, rect=False, cos_lr=False, close_mosaic=0, resume=False, amp=True, overlap_mask=True, mask_ratio=4, dropout=0.0, val=True, split=val, save_json=False, save_hybrid=False, conf=None, iou=0.7, max_det=300, half=False, dnn=False, plots=True, source=None, show=False, save_txt=False, save_conf=False, save_crop=False, show_labels=True, show_conf=True, vid_stride=1, line_thickness=3, visualize=False, augment=False, agnostic_nms=False, classes=None, retina_masks=False, boxes=True, format=torchscript, keras=False, optimize=False, int8=False, dynamic=False, simplify=False, opset=None, workspace=4, nms=False, lr0=0.01, lrf=0.01, momentum=0.937, weight_decay=0.0005, warmup_epochs=3.0, warmup_momentum=0.8, warmup_bias_lr=0.1, box=7.5, cls=0.5, dfl=1.5, pose=12.0, kobj=1.0, label_smoothing=0.0, nbs=64, hsv_h=0.015, hsv_s=0.7, hsv_v=0.4, degrees=0.0, translate=0.1, scale=0.5, shear=0.0, perspective=0.0, flipud=0.0, fliplr=0.5, mosaic=1.0, mixup=0.0, copy_paste=0.0, cfg=None, v5loader=False, tracker=botsort.yaml, save_dir=runs\detect\train15
Overriding model.yaml nc=80 with nc=13

                   from  n    params  module                                       arguments                     
  0                  -1  1       464  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [3, 16, 3, 2]                 
  1                  -1  1      4672  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [16, 32, 3, 2]                
  2                  -1  1      7360  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [32, 32, 1, True]             
  3                  -1  1     18560  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [32, 64, 3, 2]                
  4                  -1  2     49664  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [64, 64, 2, True]             
  5                  -1  1     73984  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [64, 128, 3, 2]               
  6                  -1  2    197632  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [128, 128, 2, True]           
  7                  -1  1    295424  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [128, 256, 3, 2]              
  8                  -1  1    460288  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [256, 256, 1, True]           
  9                  -1  1    164608  ultralytics.nn.modules.SPPF                  [256, 256, 5]                 
 10                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 11             [-1, 6]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 12                  -1  1    148224  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [384, 128, 1]                 
 13                  -1  1         0  torch.nn.modules.upsampling.Upsample         [None, 2, 'nearest']          
 14             [-1, 4]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 15                  -1  1     37248  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [192, 64, 1]                  
 16                  -1  1     36992  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [64, 64, 3, 2]                
 17            [-1, 12]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 18                  -1  1    123648  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [192, 128, 1]                 
 19                  -1  1    147712  ultralytics.nn.modules.Conv                  [128, 128, 3, 2]              
 20             [-1, 9]  1         0  ultralytics.nn.modules.Concat                [1]                           
 21                  -1  1    493056  ultralytics.nn.modules.C2f                   [384, 256, 1]                 
 22        [15, 18, 21]  1    753847  ultralytics.nn.modules.Detect                [13, [64, 128, 256]]          
Model summary: 225 layers, 3013383 parameters, 3013367 gradients, 8.2 GFLOPs

Transferred 319/355 items from pretrained weights
optimizer: SGD(lr=0.01) with parameter groups 57 weight(decay=0.0), 64 weight(decay=0.0005), 63 bias
train: Scanning E:\DeepFashion2Dataset\training\train\labels.cache... 191961 images, 0 backgrounds, 0 corrupt: 100%|███
val: Scanning E:\DeepFashion2Dataset\val\labels.cache... 32153 images, 0 backgrounds, 0 corrupt: 100%|██████████| 32153
Plotting labels to runs\detect\train15\labels.jpg... 
Image sizes 640 train, 640 val
Using 0 dataloader workers
Logging results to runs\detect\train15
Starting training for 30 epochs...

      Epoch    GPU_mem   box_loss   cls_loss   dfl_loss  Instances       Size
  0%|          | 0/11998 [00:03<?, ?it/s]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[22], line 7
      5 model=YOLO()
      6 #model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")  # load a pretrained model (recommended for training)
----> 7 model.train(data="E:/DeepFashion2Dataset/training/data.yaml", epochs=30, task="detect")
     10 Print("Done Successfully...")

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\engine\model.py:370, in YOLO.train(self, **kwargs)
    368     self.model = self.trainer.model
    369 self.trainer.hub_session = self.session  # attach optional HUB session
--> 370 self.trainer.train()
    371 # Update model and cfg after training
    372 if RANK in (-1, 0):

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\engine\trainer.py:191, in BaseTrainer.train(self)
    189         ddp_cleanup(self, str(file))
    190 else:
--> 191     self._do_train(world_size)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\engine\trainer.py:322, in BaseTrainer._do_train(self, world_size)
    320 batch = self.preprocess_batch(batch)
    321 preds = self.model(batch['img'])
--> 322 self.loss, self.loss_items = self.criterion(preds, batch)
    323 if RANK != -1:
    324     self.loss *= world_size

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\v8\detect\train.py:77, in DetectionTrainer.criterion(self, preds, batch)
     75 if not hasattr(self, 'compute_loss'):
     76     self.compute_loss = Loss(de_parallel(self.model))
---> 77 return self.compute_loss(preds, batch)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\v8\detect\train.py:189, in Loss.__call__(self, preds, batch)
    186 # pboxes
    187 pred_bboxes = self.bbox_decode(anchor_points, pred_distri)  # xyxy, (b, h*w, 4)
--> 189 _, target_bboxes, target_scores, fg_mask, _ = self.assigner(
    190     pred_scores.detach().sigmoid(), (pred_bboxes.detach() * stride_tensor).type(gt_bboxes.dtype),
    191     anchor_points * stride_tensor, gt_labels, gt_bboxes, mask_gt)
    193 target_bboxes /= stride_tensor
    194 target_scores_sum = max(target_scores.sum(), 1)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1501, in Module._call_impl(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1496 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1497 # this function, and just call forward.
   1498 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._backward_pre_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks
   1499         or _global_backward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1500         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1501     return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
   1502 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1503 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\_contextlib.py:115, in context_decorator.<locals>.decorate_context(*args, **kwargs)
    112 @functools.wraps(func)
    113 def decorate_context(*args, **kwargs):
    114     with ctx_factory():
--> 115         return func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\utils\tal.py:111, in TaskAlignedAssigner.forward(self, pd_scores, pd_bboxes, anc_points, gt_labels, gt_bboxes, mask_gt)
    106     device = gt_bboxes.device
    107     return (torch.full_like(pd_scores[..., 0], self.bg_idx).to(device), torch.zeros_like(pd_bboxes).to(device),
    108             torch.zeros_like(pd_scores).to(device), torch.zeros_like(pd_scores[..., 0]).to(device),
    109             torch.zeros_like(pd_scores[..., 0]).to(device))
--> 111 mask_pos, align_metric, overlaps = self.get_pos_mask(pd_scores, pd_bboxes, gt_labels, gt_bboxes, anc_points,
    112                                                      mask_gt)
    114 target_gt_idx, fg_mask, mask_pos = select_highest_overlaps(mask_pos, overlaps, self.n_max_boxes)
    116 # Assigned target

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\utils\tal.py:132, in TaskAlignedAssigner.get_pos_mask(self, pd_scores, pd_bboxes, gt_labels, gt_bboxes, anc_points, mask_gt)
    130 mask_in_gts = select_candidates_in_gts(anc_points, gt_bboxes)
    131 # Get anchor_align metric, (b, max_num_obj, h*w)
--> 132 align_metric, overlaps = self.get_box_metrics(pd_scores, pd_bboxes, gt_labels, gt_bboxes, mask_in_gts * mask_gt)
    133 # Get topk_metric mask, (b, max_num_obj, h*w)
    134 mask_topk = self.select_topk_candidates(align_metric, topk_mask=mask_gt.repeat([1, 1, self.topk]).bool())

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ultralytics\yolo\utils\tal.py:151, in TaskAlignedAssigner.get_box_metrics(self, pd_scores, pd_bboxes, gt_labels, gt_bboxes, mask_gt)
    149 ind[1] = gt_labels.long().squeeze(-1)  # b, max_num_obj
    150 # Get the scores of each grid for each gt cls
--> 151 bbox_scores[mask_gt] = pd_scores[ind[0], :, ind[1]][mask_gt]  # b, max_num_obj, h*w
    153 # (b, max_num_obj, 1, 4), (b, 1, h*w, 4)
    154 pd_boxes = pd_bboxes.unsqueeze(1).repeat(1, self.n_max_boxes, 1, 1)[mask_gt]

IndexError: index 13 is out of bounds for dimension 1 with size 13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DeepFashion2 is indexed 1-13, not 0-12, so your labels with id 13 are out of bounds. Setting nc=14 (hence making acceptable values 0-13) should let you run the code and confirm this is the problem.

Comment: the same problem when I increase or decrease the nc I found this error message: RuntimeError: Dataset 'E:\DeepFashion2Dataset\training\data.yaml' error  E:/DeepFashion2Dataset/training/data.yaml 'names' length 13 and 'nc: 14' must match.

Comment: Well you have to put a dummy class into the first index of 'names' in order to test it this way.

Comment: this will display the same error which needs matching. Dataset 'E:\DeepFashion2Dataset\training\data.yaml' error  E:/DeepFashion2Dataset/training/data.yaml 'names' length 14 and 'nc: 13' must match.

Comment: Because you went back to nc = 14. The length of 'names' and the value for 'nc' should be the same.

Comment: Yes, this is my question, if I make them matched the result is error out of bound, and when I decrease or increase I found error of not match.

Comment: When you make them both match with nc=14 and names has 14 elements (like I said you'll need to create a dummy 14th element) it still fails?

Comment: Yes, I got your point and I did so to solve the problem. Thanks so much.

Comment: This was my issue, thank you